# Which GOF pattern does MVC descend from?

Tags: design-patterns

I have looked at and studied (not necessarily memorized) GOF patterns and I don't really understand where MVC descended from.  My best guess, and it is still only a guess, but it would seem like it descends from the Bridge pattern.  But again, I can't really say.  Any one have any ideas?

Comment: here's something interesting to read, even when it looks at your question "from the other side": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119657/how-do-gang-of-four-design-patterns-fit-into-the-mvc-paradigm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MVC does not descend directly from any of them actually. MVC is technically not a design pattern it is an architectural pattern, more broad than the MoF design patterns. MVC is also broad in and of itself. There are many different implementations, each one using a different, or a combination of different design patterns.

In the *Head First Design Patterns* book they use Strategy, Composite, and the Observer patterns to implement MVC, but again, you will see it implemented using a variety of patterns.

Comment: that makes sense.  I mixed up architectural patterns with design patterns.  I am guessing architectural patterns are broader than design patters.  They would consist of patterns like SOA and things like that right?

Comment: MVC is well documented in Martin Fowler's Patterns of Enterprise Architecture. This (http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html) is well worth a read for an accurate historical perspective.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it descends from any of them.  It's architectural in nature with a focus on separation, especially UI layer.  It's a primary member of the `Separated Presentation Patterns` with the other primary members being `Model View Presenter`(MVP) and `Model View ViewModel`(MVVM).